# Compare rows without nested for-loops

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in mssql, since I am kinda new to sql I have run in to a problem. The table consists of the following data.

```
    ID     |     Long     |     Lat      |     TimeStamp
-----------+--------------+--------------+------------------    
    123    |      54      |     18       |    2012-12-02...       
    143    |      31      |     35       |    2011-09-14...
    322    |      53      |     19       |    2012-11-29...
```

And so on...

I have written a boolean function which checks a condition for a pair of long and lats. I have also written a function which gives the distance between a pair of long and lats. What I want to do is to add a column with the distance to the row which is closest to the the current row and also passes the boolean function and are sufficiently close to each other in time. The database table consists of several million rows, I therefore refrain from using nested for-loops, how would you guys tackle this large dataset? Do mssql have some smart way of doing this?

All help is welcome <3

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to comapare 1 million records to 1 million other records in your function, giving you 1 trillion values to work with. In my opinion, SQL is not really going to help you manage that many records, so you'll have to do some work yourself and also only do bits of work at a time. There may be a better way, but I would do the following:

1. Add the following columns to the table: `calculated` `destination`, `distance`
2. Run an algorithm periodically or if a new record is added. This algorithm only needs to run for records where `calculated` is false.

The algorithm can work something like below:

1. With the current record, loop through each record that has `calculated` as `true` and calculate the distance to that location. if the location is the shortest thus far, set a variable to temporarily store the `destination` and `distance`.
2. After the loop has finished, you have the shortest `destination` and `distance` for the current location. Update that in the database and also set the `calculated` flag to `true`.
3. Now compare this distance to the distance in the record for the destination. If it is shorter, also update that record.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped me to solve the issue. My main problem is that I suck so badly at SQL that it is embarrassing :D However, as ususal with the help of stackoverflow and google everything is possible. Thanks again!